# Can we use Custom Label in additional email address

Tags: email-alert, customlabel

Is it possible to user Custom labels in Addition email address field on Approval process email alerts?

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot use custom labels in email alerts. But there's a workaround for this. You can create an email field in the object and then set the label as the default value of the field.Then use this field in the approval email alerts.